# Why does this bash idiom require eval?

Tags: bash, array, command-substitution, eval

Why does this produces `_results=""`...

```
_results="$( grep ${_gopts[@]} )"
```

And this produces the desired _results (list of SSHFS entries in fstab)...

```
_results="$( eval grep ${_gopts[@]} )"
```

The _gopts array is identical in both cases and consists of...

```
declare -p _gopts
declare -a _gopts=([0]="--extended-regexp" [1]="--with-filename" [2]="--recursive" [3]="--include" [4]="fstab" [5]="'^[^#]*sshfs#'" [6]="/etc")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the extra quotes around the 5th element (the regexp: `[5]="'^[^#]*sshfs#'"`).

The grep command will be passed an argument of the form `'^regex'` instead of `^regex`, which will not match, ever (there's no way for `regex` to both follow a single quote *and* start at the beginning of the line, at the same time).

Remove them, and then quote the array expansion (`"${_gopts[@]}"` instead of `${_gopts[@]}`):

```
declare -p _gopts
declare -a _gopts=([0]="--extended-regexp" [1]="--with-filename" [2]="--recursive" [3]="--include" [4]="fstab" [5]="^[^#]*sshfs#" [6]="/etc")

_results=$( grep "${_gopts[@]}" )
```

You may also want to use single instead of double quotes in the array declaration: double quotes aren't necessary, since no element contains variables & other expansions.